# How does a 10th level Incantatrix count when adding several metamagic feats?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, prestige-class, metamagic

The capstone ability of the Incantatrix prestige class (Player's Guide to Faerûn, p. 61), Improved Metamagic, says:

> At 10th level, an incantatrix has mastered metamagic to such an extent that whenever she uses a metamagic feat, the required increase in spell level (if any) is reduced by one (minimum +1 spell level).

If an Incantatrix wishes to cast a spell with multiple metamagic feats, such as an empowered maximized *fireball* (8th level slot, 3 from the *fireball* +2 from Empower, +3 from Maximize); will her Improved Metamagic ability reduce each and every metamagic level increase by one (thus using a 6th level spell slot) or the combined metamagic level increase will be reduced by one (needing a 7th level spell slot)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Improved Metamagic affects the cost of applying metamagic feats individually, so your empowered maximized fireball will end up filling a 6th level spell slot.

From the "Player's Guide to Faerun":

> Improved Metamagic (Su): At 10th level, an incantatrix has mastered metamagic to such an extent that **whenever she uses a metamagic feat, the required increase in spell level (if any) is reduced by one** (minimum +1 spell level). For example, a wizard incantatrix could prepare a quickened fireball as a 6th-level spell instead of a 7th-level spell.

Emphasis added by me.

This proves that it is how the individual feats costs, not the end result that is adjusted by this ability.

**Follow up on comments**

There is nothing on this in the [Errata](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata), but the description of *Improved Metamagic* goes on to say:

> This benefit also applies to the incantatrix's other class abilities.
>   Thus, the DC for using her metamagic effect or cooperative metamagic
>   ability is reduced appropriately **for the metamagic feats involved**, and
>   she spends fewer charges when using metamagic spell trigger.

Again emphasis added by me.

I have always read this as modifying the feats (plural) cost individually, like we see with the *Arcane Thesis* feat or multiple *Practical Metamagic* feats.

The text can be interpreted to mean only a single-level reduction, or only with a single feat, but this doesn't seem to match with the implementation of similarly worded effects (*Arcane Thesis*, *Practical Metamagic*).

If this still isn't enough, then it would have to come down to a Game Master ruling.

Comment: I'm not sure how quoting the text back to asker answers the question. That is, an incantatrix that's applying *two or more* metamagic feats to a spell isn't applying just *a* metamagic feat to a spell. Although it's a stretch to read it this way, the question's been asked, so it seems it *can* be. An equally sketchy—but still possible—alternative would have the extraordinary ability improved metamagic do nothing if the incantatrix applies more than one metamagic feat to a spell! (That is, inferring from after the bolded *and whenever she uses more than one metamagic feat, nothing happens*.)

Comment: I favour the interpretation given; reading "[whenever a singular ability of a category is applied] then X" as resulting in "apply X to the total of the abilities of that category" would, in my understanding, result in a rather massive change to how D&D 3.x is usually interpreted; as would reading it as "[Whenever only one ability of a category...] then X".